# Jquery mouse Hover on Div class

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to add mouse hover effect. Its a product section which has the same div tags, if i hover on the image class, i want to show the title only for the current image but its showing all the title on mouseover.

Below code works onmouseover but enable all the class name = "highlight". If i hover on the first div =('top-section'), the script should enable only the first class="highlight" name inside it.

Html

```
<div class ="featured">
    <div class="featured-section">
    <a href="#" class="featured-link">
    <div class="top-section">
        <img src="1.jpeg">
        <span class="highlight">
            <h3 class="title">title 1</h3>
        </span>
    </div>
    
    </a>
    </div>

   <div class="featured-section">
    <a href="#" class="featured-link">
    <div class="top-section">
        <img src="2.jpeg">
        <span class="highlight">
            <h3 class="title">title 2</h3>
        </span>
    </div>
    
    </a>
    </div>

   <div class="featured-section">
    <a href="#" class="featured-link">
    <div class="top-section">
        <img src="3.jpeg">
        <span class="highlight">
            <h3 class="title">title 3</h3>
        </span>
    </div>
    
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
  $(".top-section").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      $(".highlight").addClass("show").fadeIn();

    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.highlight').removeClass("show").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you select all `.highlight` elements in the DOM when the events fire. You need to select only the ones relevant to the `.top-section` which fired the event.

To do that use the `this` keyword in the event handler to refer to the element which raised the event, then `find()` from there:

```js
$(".top-section").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).find(".highlight").addClass("show").fadeIn();
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find('.highlight').removeClass("show").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight { 
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="featured">
  <div class="featured-section">
    <a href="#" class="featured-link">
      <div class="top-section">
        <img src="1.jpeg">
        <span class="highlight">
          <h3 class="title">title 1</h3>
        </span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="featured-section">
    <a href="#" class="featured-link">
      <div class="top-section">
        <img src="2.jpeg">
        <span class="highlight">
          <h3 class="title">title 2</h3>
        </span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="featured-section">
    <a href="#" class="featured-link">
      <div class="top-section">
        <img src="3.jpeg">
        <span class="highlight">
          <h3 class="title">title 3</h3>
        </span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

That being said, it's worth noting that your logic can be created more effectively, and more performantly using CSS alone:

```css
.highlight { 
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  display: block;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, height 0.3s;
}

.top-section:hover .highlight {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="featured">
  <div class="featured-section">
    <a href="#" class="featured-link">
      <div class="top-section">
        <img src="1.jpeg">
        <span class="highlight">
          <h3 class="title">title 1</h3>
        </span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="featured-section">
    <a href="#" class="featured-link">
      <div class="top-section">
        <img src="2.jpeg">
        <span class="highlight">
          <h3 class="title">title 2</h3>
        </span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="featured-section">
    <a href="#" class="featured-link">
      <div class="top-section">
        <img src="3.jpeg">
        <span class="highlight">
          <h3 class="title">title 3</h3>
        </span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$(".top-section").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      // .children() creates a jquery object containing all the childrens of the 
      // current instance of .top-sector, .last() selects the last of them
      $(this).children().last().addClass("show").fadeIn();

    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).children().last().removeClass("show").fadeOut();
    }
});
```